# Insert file path via counsel

Tags: ivy

A common part of my workflow is to copy and paste file paths into Emacs. This is usually done by navigating to the file in my desktop environment or from a terminal.

What would be more convenient is for me to do so via `counsel-find-file`, navigate to the file path and then insert at the point in the current buffer (or some similar workflow with autocompletion) instead of actually opening the file.

Is there any way to do this in Emacs?

Comment: I guess this a bit subjective, but the `ivy`, `counsel` and `swiper` packages are so intricately tied and overlapping (they're part of the [same project](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/)) that I advocate using only a single tag for simplicity, to avoid giving rise to something like the smorgasbord of `org` tags. In fact, I may go as far as suggesting to make the `ivy`, `counsel` and `swiper` tags synonymous. As justification, notice that the answer to your `counsel-find-file` question was `ivy`-specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What would be more convenient is for me to do so via `counsel-find-file`, navigate to the file path and then insert at the point in the current buffer (or some similar workflow with autocompletion) instead of actually opening the file.

Ivy provides a built-in way to do this. During Ivy completion you can invoke custom actions on the current candidate; see [`(ivy) Actions`](http://oremacs.com/swiper/#actions). One of the standard actions, "insert", is bound to <kbd>i</kbd> by default.

So, during `counsel-find-file`, you can type <kbd>M-o</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to insert the currently selected filename into the current buffer.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of `counsel-find-file`:

```
(defun my-counsel-insert-file-path ()
  "Insert file path."
  (interactive)
  (unless (featurep 'counsel) (require 'counsel))
  (ivy-read "Find file: " 'read-file-name-internal
            :matcher #'counsel--find-file-matcher
            :action
            (lambda (x)
              (insert x))))
```